# Can't add more widgets inside container, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, widget, containers

I am trying to make the UI as (Image No 1), i have added rows and column widgets, and came through half of the Container.
Now i want to add a divider line and add a button on left side and text on right side as shown in Image No 1. My current UI is as shown in Image No 2, and code for that is also provided. Tried many ways but cant find a solution, Please help :)

[image: UI Design]

[image: Current Progress]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'disability_page.dart';

class DecisionMakingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DecisionMakingPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DecisionMakingPage> createState() => _DecisionMakingPageState();
}

class _DecisionMakingPageState extends State<DecisionMakingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DisabilityPage()));
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 24),
            child: Text(
              "Decision Making",
              style: TextStyle(
                 color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 0),
            child: Text(
              "Select a Game",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                fontSize: 36,
              ),
            ),
          ),



      Container(
        height: 150,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, left: 35, right: 35),
        
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          
        ),
        
        child: Row(
          
          children: [
            
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35,left: 30),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Tetris Game",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary, fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                  Text("Level 1",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary, fontSize: 13
                      ),
                    ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),

            const Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, bottom: 40, top: 10),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage("lib/assests/images/tetris_game.png"),
                  
                  
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
          
        ), 

        
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your row inside of another column. This parent column will contain the first row you already built, followed by a divider, and then another Row at the end that contains the Button and the Text.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DisabilityPage()));
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 24),
        child: Text(
          "Decision Making",
          style: TextStyle(
             color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 0),
        child: Text(
          "Select a Game",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
            fontSize: 36,
          ),
        ),
      ),



  Container(
    height: 150,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, left: 35, right: 35),
    
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      
    ),

    
    
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          
          children: [
            
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35,left: 30),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Tetris Game",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary, fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                  Text("Level 1",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary, fontSize: 13
                      ),
                    ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),

            const Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, bottom: 40, top: 10),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage("lib/assests/images/tetris_game.png"),
                  
                  
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
          
        ),
        Divider(),
        Row(
          children: [
            YourButton(), 
            Spacer(),
            Text('EST: 3 mins')
          ],
        )
      ],
    ), 

    
  )
],
```